# Some of the variables does not write to the file in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a certain variables to the files, but the weird thing is, after I finish writing it to the file, 2 of the variables doesn't get write to the file. The variables are **average** and **grade**.

Here the code:

```
//  Function to modify a student's exam scores.
    void ArtStudent::modifyScore(string newName, int newIndian, int newEnglish, int newMath, int newHistory, int newMoral, int newEcon, int newCommerce, int newArt) {


    map<string, tuple<int, char,int, int, int, int, int, int , int, int> > data;

    // Read file and fill data map
    ifstream studentRec("ArtStudentRecord.txt");
    string line;

    while (getline(studentRec, line))
    {
       string name;
       int studentNo;
       char gender;
       int indian = 0;
       int english = 0;
       int math = 0;
       int history = 0; 
       int moral = 0;
       int economic = 0;
       int commerce = 0;
       int art = 0;

       stringstream ss(line);
       ss >> name >> studentNo >> gender >> indian >> english >> math >> history >> moral >> economic >> commerce >> art ;
       data[name] = make_tuple(studentNo, gender, indian, english, math, history, moral, economic, commerce, art);

    }

    studentRec.close();
    // Modify data


    auto it = data.find(newName) ; // gets current student record from the map
    if (it == data.end()) // student not in map, that's an error
     return ;
    // now it->second holds your student data
    // an auto here could be better, but we want to be sure of type
    auto studentNo = get<0>(it->second) ;
    auto gender = get<1>(it->second) ;

    // Modify Data
    data[newName] = make_tuple(studentNo, gender, newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral, newEcon, newCommerce, newArt);


    // Open same file for output, overwrite existing data
    ofstream ofs("ArtStudentRecord.txt");

    for (auto entry = data.begin(); entry != data.end(); ++entry)
    {
        tie(studentNo, gender, newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral,  newEcon, newCommerce, newArt) = entry->second;
        double average = averageScore(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral, newEcon, newCommerce, newArt);
        char grade = getGrade(newIndian,newEnglish, newMath, newHistory, newMoral, newEcon, newCommerce, newArt, average);

         ofs << left <<  setw(15) << entry->first << setw(15) << studentNo << setw(15) << gender << setw(15) << newIndian << setw(15) << newEnglish << setw(15) << newMath << setw(15) << newHistory << setw(15) <<  newMoral << setw(15) << 
            newEcon << setw(15) << newCommerce << setw(15) << newArt << setw(15) << right << average << grade << endl;
    }
    ofs.close();


}
```

There are only two variables that don't get write to the files, **average** and **gender**

For the sake of clarity, I have two functions that do some algorithms to calculate average score and getting a grade based on the average score.

Calculate average score function

```
    double ArtStudent::averageScore(int malay, int english, int math, int history, int moral, int econ, int commerce, int art) {

        double result = (malay + english + math + history + moral + econ + commerce + art) / 8;
        return result;
    }
```

Getting the student's grade function

```
// get Grade for student
    char ArtStudent::getGrade(int malay, int english, int math, int history, int moral, int econ, int commerce, int art, double avScore ) {

        if (malay < 60 || english < 60 || math < 60 || history < 60 || moral < 60 || econ < 60 || commerce < 60 || art < 60) {
            return 'F';
        }

        if (avScore < 60) {

            return 'F';
        } else if (avScore > 59 && avScore < 70){
            return 'D';
        } else if (avScore > 69 && avScore < 80) {
            return 'C';
        } else if (avScore > 79 && avScore < 90) {
            return 'B';
        } else {
            return 'A';
        }
    }
```

After I run the function, I will always get this result

```
Batman         316536         M              33             99             22             31             44             44             55             12
```

As you can see, it will write 11 variables, while it supposed to be 13 variables

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied the part of your code where you write to the file and made a test mockup. I don't know what text editor you are using that you don't see it, but your two last variables are written to the file as well.

And I believe you meant to say that the problem is with variables average and grade, not gender?

The average and grade are written with no spaces between them

```
(...) << std::right << average << grade << std::endl;
```

They'll appear as one variable like 65C. Moreover you used std::right, so average and grade will be aligned to the right of the 15 spaces you set earlier with setw(15). (Which will make them stand a bit farther apart from the other values)

It would seem that your values are being written to the file.

This is the code I tested:

```
std::ofstream ofs("ArtStudentRecord.txt");

std::string name = "FooBar";
int studentNo = 111111;
char gender = 'M';
int newIndian = 50;
int newEnglish = 80;
int newMath = 50;
int newHistory = 80;
int newMoral = 50;
int newEcon = 80;
int newCommerce = 50;
int newArt = 80;
double average = 65;
char grade = 'C';

ofs << std::left <<  std::setw(15) << name << std::setw(15) << studentNo
    << std::setw(15) << gender << std::setw(15) << newIndian << std::setw(15)
    << newEnglish << std::setw(15) << newMath << std::setw(15) << newHistory
    << std::setw(15) << newMoral << std::setw(15) << newEcon << std::setw(15)
    << newCommerce << std::setw(15) << newArt << std::setw(15)
    << std::right << average << grade << std::endl;

ofs.close();
```

And the result,

```
FooBar         111111         M              50             80             50             80             50             80             50             80                          65C
```

(Notice how the average and grade are slightly separated from the other values)

On a side note, you should always check if your files opened successfully before using them.

```
std::ofstream file( "PathOfAFile" );
if ( file.is_open() ) {
    // Do things with file
    file.close();
}
else {
    // ERROR
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? because it still doesn't show up on the notepad

Comment: I'm using notepad++ and it shows up for me. Try another editor. (It also shows up in the regular notepad though)

Comment: I tried on sublime text as well but still it doesn't show up.

Comment: What is the problem ?, I'm really confused right now. I compiled it using visual studio 2010

Comment: I compiled it in VS2010 as well. Make sure in your notepad that the average and grade didn't go into the next line because there wasn't enough space to show the whole line. The file generated with this testing code has 183 bytes here, can you check yours?

Comment: The ArtStudentRecord.txt has 167 bytes only

Comment: Hmm, so what was the problem then?

Comment: I forgot to close the file, I used your solution and it works fine

Comment: By the way do you how to replace all variables with another variables in visual studio 2010?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81513/discussion-between-aslg-and-airsoftfreak).